# Nuxt 3 Production in Apache2 with subdirectory

Tags: apache, nuxt.js, pm2, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server running with Node/NodeJS and P2M installed. I want to deploy Nuxt 3 project into a subdirectory /app/. On my /var/www/html there is a other project (client-side).

What I have done, running `nuxt build` and in my `nuxt.config.js` the following attributes:

```
... other config
server: {
  port: 8080,
},
router: {
  base: "/app/",
},
app: {
  base: "/app/",
  head: {
    meta: [],
    link: [],
  },
},
vite: {
  base: "/app/",
  plugins: [svgLoader(), dynamicImport()],
},
....
```

I put everything from `.output` into into `/var/www/html/app`

Into this folder I run the following `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js -- --port 8080`

In my apache config I have the following:

```
ProxyPass /app/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://localhost:8080/
```

The `ecosystem.config.js` look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'app',
      port: '8080',
      cwd: '/var/www/html/app',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max',
      script: './server/index.mjs'
    }
  ]
}
```

On my website `https://example.net/app` I see the app but it is trying to get the `_nuxt` files in example `https://example.net/_nuxt/entry.06c30429.js`. I don't want this on the root folder but in `https://example.net/app/_nuxt/entry.06c30429.js` so I can have multiple projects. Now I just place a _nuxt folder into `/var/www/html` but this will only be limited on 1 SSR project. Not very ideal. I tried many things including in `nuxt.config.js` specify `buildDir: "app",`

Also the router is not working correctly. Navigating directly to `https://example.net/app` I see the app. But on page refresh it navigates to `https://example.net/`. The issue above is more important for me to solve.

I have no clue how to solve it as I have tried many different things.

[image: File Browser]

If I have this in `nuxt.config.js`

```
app: {
  baseURL: "/app/",
  head: {
    meta: [],
    link: [],
  },
},
```

I am getting a error `404 Cannot find any path matching /.`

[image]

[image]

If I head to /app/app strangely I see the page but error collecting the _nuxt files example `https://example.net/app/_nuxt/vue.f36acd1f.a74ff25b.js`. These do exist. Adding this in Apache config won't work eiter. Everything is very strange.

```
ProxyPass /app/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://localhost:8080/

<Location "/app/_nuxt/">
    ProxyPass !
</Location>

Alias /app/_nuxt/ /var/www/html/app/_nuxt
<Directory /var/www/html/app/_nuxt>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride None  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

PM2 logs

[image]

Project: Nuxt 3.8.2 & Vue 3.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have Nuxt playing nicely with an Apache reverse proxy with a URL that contains a subdirectory, you need two things:

1. the `app.baseURL` item in your `nuxt.config.js` set to your subdirectory, e.g. `/app`:

```
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
       //...
       app: {
           baseURL: "/app"
       },
       //...
    )}
```

2. The following in your Apache configuration:

```
    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app
```

Note the "/app" at the end has been added, and I have "/app" as the second argument to ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, rather than "/app/". (I have seen some users have issues with the trailing `/`)

This way, Nuxt is serving the application at `localhost:8080/app`, and Apache is passing `example.url/app` to that same location. Requests to Nuxt assets should then show up as being sent to `example.url/app/_nuxt/<asset>` and should resolve correctly.

I also have no configuration specific to nuxt under my <Location /app> tag (only authentication related configurations), so try without that as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked finally. I did many things wrong.

Comment: @ChahinDev It look me many configuration attempts to come across the right one; glad you got it working!